# Range Based Loop C++

Tags: c++, oop

How would you implement a class in C++ using constant time and constant space such that the following would work?

```cpp
for (auto &x : Range{0, 10}) {
    cout << x << " ";
}
```

My initial idea was to create a vector but wasn't constant space. Curious how this would be done.

Comment: Two variables, one for start, one for end. You will also need an iterator, and `begin` and `end` functions.

Comment: Why do you want to know, how to do it? Is it a coding puzzle from some website that promises that doing their coding puzzles will turn anyone into a C++ uberhacker? Unfortunately this is not true.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was interested in trying to translate some of my Python code into C++. Of course, I could have done `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`, but was curious if this could be done.

Comment: Boost [irange](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) provides that functionality.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a range-based for loop to work, you need:

- `begin()` returning an iterator
- `end()` returning an iterator

On the iterator, you need:

- `operator!=()` to compare at least against `end()`
- `operator++()` to increment the loop iterator
- `operator*()` for dereference of the iterator

So you'll need to implement two classes: `Range` and the corresponding iterator.

Loop starts at `it = begin()` and goes while `it != end()` (technically, `end()` is evaluated only once per loop, stored and we compare against the stored value); in each loop, it's dereferenced as `*it` and after the body, incremented as `++it;`.